# Splitting string and performing calculations from delimited string tokens C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, optimization

I delimited the string expression "**1 plus 1 minus 2 plus 2 minus 2 minus 5 plus 10**".Gathered the tokens in string[] and started coding Jargon.
1 plus 1 minus 2 plus 2 minus 2 minus 5 plus 10=5

```
    public int Calculate(string expression)
    {
        //TODO: implement this
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
            return 0;
        //expression = "100 plus 100 minus 200";

        string[] tokens = expression.Split();

        int i= 0;
        int result=0;

        for (; i < tokens.Length; )
        {

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            if (i < 1)
            {
                a = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else if (i % 2 != 0 && tokens[i].ToString() == "plus")
            {
                i++;
                b = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
                a = result;
                result = a + b;
                i = i + 2;


            }

            if (tokens[i].ToString() == "plus")
            {
                i++;
                b = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
                result += a + b;
                i = i + 2;

            }
            else if(i>1)
            {
                a = result;

                b = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
                result = a - b;
                i=i+1;

            }

            else
            {
                i++;
                //a = result;
                b = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
                result += a - b;
                i++;

            }



        }


            return result;

    }
```

It calculated the some basic calculation operations but stuck on above mentioned string operation.I need to return integer value from tokenized string by performing calculations 
Can any one please suggest me better solution?

Comment: What problems are you having with your soluition?  Is it working, if not, why not?  Does it not compile, does it throw an exception, is the output wrong, or what?

Comment: I straight up have no idea what you're doing

Comment: Did you step thru this code in debug?  Why the i = i + 2: ?

Comment: @Blam Because he's parsing two token per loop, the number and it's sign.

Comment: @Servy he's already doing i++ just before. i += 2; should just be i++;

Comment: @Servy i = i + 2; skips the next token

Comment: @the_lotus I agree he's not properly managing the loop counter, but the fact that it's going up by two isn't the problem, the problem is that he's manipulating it all over the place when he just shouldn't be.

Comment: @Servy you are right on that

Comment: @Servy Just how does  i = i + 2 not skip the next token?

Comment: @Blam The whole loop counter manipulation is just all messed up.  It's changed all over the place and at times when it shouldn't be.  One valid option would be to just increment it by two in the `for` loop, another is to increment it by one twice.

Comment: @Blam If you only ever access the item at `i`, it would.  If you access `i` as well as the item before/after it, then it doesn't.

Comment: @Servy Given he only accesses the item at i how would i = i + 2 not skip the next token?

Comment: @Blam The whole thing is just messed up.  As I said, a perfectly valid sensible solution may involve incrementing `i` by two.  It's not an inherently flawed concept.  The *intent* behind doing so is clearly that each loop iteration handles two tokens.  As I've said several times, this particular solution doesn't handle it correctly, but it's not like changing that to `i++` just fixes it.  The whole loop counter management is entirely off.

Comment: @Servy Clearly I was commenting on that code not another approach.  i++ fixes one problem.  For you to state that is not one problem does not help a clearly confused OP.

Comment: @Blam It doesn't even ensure that the loop counter management it is correct though.  He's incrementing `i` in way too many places.  Even if they were all single increments he'd be skipping items.  Most of them need to be removed entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to perform operation on this string but your operators are in the form of string like *minus* for `-` or *plus* for `+`.

So basically your string

```
string expression="1 plus 1 minus 2 plus 2 minus 2 minus 5 plus 10";
```

should be equivalent to

```
string myExpression= "1 + 1 - 2 + 2 - 2 - 5 + 10"
```

and your result should be the math calculation of this ie. `5`

For that [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) would be handy for you  and can try this solution

```
public int Calculate()
{
    string expression = "1 plus 1 minus 2 plus 2 minus 2 minus 5 plus 10";
    string mathExpression = expression.Replace("plus", "+").Replace("minus", "-");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var value = dt.Compute(mathExpression, "");
    return (int)value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq `Aggregate` method and try this. Off course, if the expression it's not well formed it may fail.

```
    var expression = "1 plus 1 minus 2 plus 2 minus 2 minus 5 plus 10";

    var exp = expression.Split(' ');

    var count = 0;
    var result = exp.Aggregate(Convert.ToInt32(exp[0]), (acc, next) =>
        {
            count++;
            if (next == "plus")
                return acc + Convert.ToInt32(exp[count]);
            if (next == "minus")
                return acc - Convert.ToInt32(exp[count]);
            return acc;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way to much stuff.

The first number is always the starting point, your initial result.
Then you need to loop all tokens by steps on 2.
On each loop, the first item is the operator and the 2nd item is the number.
Depending on the first item [i] you assign the value [i+1] to the result.

```
// This assume perfect parameter
public int Calculate(string expression)
{

 int result = 0;
 string[] tokens = null;

 tokens = expression.Split(" ");
 result = Int32.Parse(tokens[0]);

 for (int i = 1; i <= tokens.Length - 1; i += 2) {
   if (tokens[i] == "plus")
     result += Int32.Parse(tokens[i + 1]);
   else if (tokens[i] == "minus")
     result -= Int32.Parse(tokens[i + 1]);
 }

 return result;
```

}